# Finder doesn't show newly created files anymore unless restarted

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

The title says it (I mean, when a new file is created in an other application). This started happening today, and I think this may be related to an error message which I got the first time in yesterday evening:

[image: screenshot]

This is the link from screenshot: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1387401 — just in case you want to check it out.
And, of course, I did a reboot after that message.

The issue is not reproduced in 100% of the trials, but it's there…
I checked the disk with Disk Utility and it says it's OK.
What could it be?

### Analysis

The output of `df -ki`:

```
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1      487385240 443717640  43411600    92% 110993408 10852900   91%   /
devfs                 202       202         0   100%       703        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts              0         0         0   100%         0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home           0         0         0   100%         0        0  100%   /home
```

After deleting some trash:

```
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1      487385240 391070420  96058820    81% 97831603 24014705   80%   /
devfs                 201       201         0   100%      698        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts              0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home           0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /home
```

Comment: Please include in your question the output of `df -ki`.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Done.

Comment: You need to free up disk space in order for OS X to run properly. You’re teetering on the edge of [not being able to even boot it](http://macs.about.com/od/faq1/f/How-Much-Free-Drive-Space-Do-I-Need.htm)

Answer (score 2):

From the output of your `df -ki` command, two numbers are telling you are beyond the red frontier of safe disk use.

Look at the line terminating with `/` which is your main visible and used disk partition. When the columns `Capacity` and `%iused` display numbers above **90%**, then any search for a new free space or free `inode` is a real nightmare.
To tell you the truth the internal algorithm used by the MacOS X file system switched mode and is already in fight for breath.

- When these two numbers are below **50%** you are in the green area, nothing to schedule, just work.
- When they are between **50%** and **90%** you are in the red one, you should schedule your next disk or computer buy.
- Between **90%** and **100%** you are in the black area. You are fighting against a system in survival mode. Your risk of crash is pretty high. You can't anymore trust the journaling function.
- At **100%** you are not anywhere.

### What to do

Estimate correctly your disk need for the next three years and buy a new disk. Once installed a new disk should let you with at least these two numbers below **50%**.

Or, if this is feasable, change your disk space use to suit reality:

- identify and clean garbage,
- make external archives.

Comment: The disk is not replaceable. Can it be repaired?

Comment: Your disk isn't damaged, on the contrary it is perfectly working… under deadly pressure. It is deadly full. You have to replace it or to replace the computer. One other way out is to buy an external disk and migrate on it what you can consider as archives. You should migrate at least 250 GB of archives on an external disk at least 500 GB large. This advice is theoretical since I can't see your **real need**.

Comment: You might also look within your home folder for any abnormal filesystem use. If you find something abnormal on this search, I suggest you to make another question with details on this other problem.

Comment: Okay, I understand. BTW, I deleted some trash now, and now I'm at 80%.

Comment: @SargeBorsch http://thexlab.com/faqs/freeingspace.html